# Trouble resetting phone and removing Family Link

Tags: factory-reset, google-family-link

**Introduction:**
Resetting an Android phone can be very tricky when Family Link is active, as I discovered when attempting to perform a factory data reset on my son's phone. Despite uninstalling the Family Link app, a persistent "Action Not Allowed" message prevented the reset, citing lingering parental controls.

**The Problem:**
The device displayed an "Action Not Allowed" error when trying to execute a factory data reset, indicating that Family Link parental controls were still in effect. Clicking "Learn more" reiterated that an administrator had the power to monitor and manage apps.

**Initial Attempts:**

- **Reinstalling Family Link:** Attempting to regain control over the settings by reinstalling and configuring the Family Link app on a
  parent device.
- **Removing Supervision via Family Link:** Trying to remove the son's account from the Family Link supervision directly on the parent's
  device.
- **Checking for Additional Google Accounts:** Ensuring no other Google accounts on the device had administrative control linked to Family
  Link.

Despite these efforts, the reset was still blocked.

Comment: Hi Borgon, this site works differently. Its questio and answers. Please remove the solution and add it as an answer.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Borgon. This looks like a good potential for [self Q&A](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), though the solution should go to the Answer box :). Otherwise, could it possibly that there was a question that you found but couldn't post an answer there? Please let me know, thanks!

Comment: Thanks Rohit, I've split it up

Answer (score 1):

**The Breakthrough:** A crucial step involved checking the "Device admin apps" setting on the phone, which indicated that Family Link parental controls were still active. The "Deactivate" option was greyed out, preventing the removal of administrative rights through the device settings.

**The Solution:** The resolution came when I removed the Google account associated with Family Link from the device. By navigating to "Settings" > "Accounts and backup" > "Accounts" and removing the account, the administrative control was lifted, allowing a factory data reset.